# JFileChooser save with extension

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I created a file then I need to save it as .docx extension, but my code saves it as .txt how can I change the extension?

```
    JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
    saveFile.setDialogTitle("Save a file");
    saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
    File selectedFile = saveFile.getSelectedFile();

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(selectedFile);
    fileWriter.write(editedDoc.toString());
    editedDoc.save(selectedFile.toString(), true);
```

Comment: Anything wrong with the [How to use file chooser, filtering a list of files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters) tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // sets the file chooser to be able to locate and overwrite .docx file type only
 saveFile.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Word", "docx"));
```

In case the user has already entered .docx, use this code.

```
// get the full path of the file
String absolutePath = saveFile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();  

// does the selected file have an extension of docx?
// if yes then exclude the extension, if no, then add .docx to the file name
if (!absolutePath.substring(absolutePath.lastIndexOf(".")+1).equals("docx"))     
     absolutePath += ".docx";                                                     

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(absolutePath);
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `String#endsWith` instead of `substring` - personally it's jus easier to type and read :P

Comment: Note the drop down list can have multiple file name extensions, simply re-use the addChoosableFileFilter().

Comment: @MadProgrammer up to you.

Comment: @alhinai-hamed I have misunderstanding in jcombobox loop, could you please check that for me? if you're willing to help please send me ur email, I'll send you my code as zip file.

Comment: @mona Feel free to create a new question, and tag me in the comment. I will see if I can solve it, otherwise someone else might be able to.

Comment: @alhinai-hamed I taged you in my question.